# Error JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray in android?

Tags: java, android, json

Here I am trying to send my json array to mysql database.When I run this code I get this error:

```
com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value {"msg":false,"status":false} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

And here's my code:

```
private void insertToDb() {
        billType = (invEstSwitch.isChecked() ? textViewEstimate : textViewInvoice)
                .getText().toString();
        try {
            jsonObject.put("custInfo", custSelected.toString());
            jsonObject.put("invoiceNo", textViewInvNo.getText().toString());
            jsonObject.put("barcode", barCode.getText().toString());
            jsonObject.put("desc", itemDesc.getText().toString());
            jsonObject.put("weight", weightLine.getText().toString());
            jsonObject.put("rate", rateAmount.getText().toString());
            jsonObject.put("makingAmt", makingAmount.getText().toString());
            jsonObject.put("net_rate", netRate.getText().toString());
            jsonObject.put("itemTotal", itemtotal.getText().toString());
            jsonObject.put("vat", textViewVat.getText().toString());
            jsonObject.put("sum_total", textViewSum.getText().toString());
            jsonObject.put("bill_type", billType);
            jsonObject.put("date", textViewCurrentDate.getText().toString());


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            itemSelectedJson.put(index, jsonObject);
            index++;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        final JsonArrayRequest arrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, INVEST_URL, itemSelectedJson, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                Log.d("RESPONSE", response.toString());
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("JSON ERROR", error.toString());
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
                return headers;
            }
        };

        final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        queue.add(arrayRequest);

    }
```

I also tried displaying the json array inside a text view.It displays the following json array.

```
[
    {
        "custInfo": "Ujwal 9975022560",
        "rate": "24000",
        "weight": "21.00000",
        "desc": "GENTS ANGTHI 22k NO STONE",
        "makingAmt": "200",
        "sum_total": "RS.104188.92",
        "vat": "RS.2042.92",
        "itemTotal": "51073",
        "barcode": "BQSP78BB",
        "net_rate": "24200",
        "date": "2015-12-01",
        "invoiceNo": "1",
        "bill_type": "Estimate"
    },
    {
        "custInfo": "Ujwal 9975022560",
        "rate": "24000",
        "weight": "21.00000",
        "desc": "GENTS ANGTHI 22k NO STONE",
        "makingAmt": "200",
        "sum_total": "RS.104188.92",
        "vat": "RS.2042.92",
        "itemTotal": "51073",
        "barcode": "BQSP78BB",
        "net_rate": "24200",
        "date": "2015-12-01",
        "invoiceNo": "1",
        "bill_type": "Estimate"
    }
]
```

I tested this json array on json lint.It is a valid JSON.
As suggested I changed to json object request.Now I am getting a Response it say RESPONSE: `{"msg":false,"status":false}` I get it at 
`public void onResponse(JSONObject response) { Log.d("RESPONSE", response.toString()); }` what does that mean?

```
private void insertToDb() {
        billType = (invEstSwitch.isChecked() ? textViewEstimate : textViewInvoice)
                .getText().toString();
        try {
            jsonObject.put("custInfo", custSelected.toString());
            jsonObject.put("invoiceNo", textViewInvNo.getText().toString());
            jsonObject.put("barcode", barCode.getText().toString());
            jsonObject.put("desc", itemDesc.getText().toString());
            jsonObject.put("weight", weightLine.getText().toString());
            jsonObject.put("rate", rateAmount.getText().toString());
            jsonObject.put("makingAmt", makingAmount.getText().toString());
            jsonObject.put("net_rate", netRate.getText().toString());
            jsonObject.put("itemTotal", itemtotal.getText().toString());
            jsonObject.put("vat", textViewVat.getText().toString());
            jsonObject.put("sum_total", textViewSum.getText().toString());
            jsonObject.put("bill_type", billType);
            jsonObject.put("date", textViewCurrentDate.getText().toString());


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            itemSelectedJson.put(index, jsonObject);
            index++;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonobj.put("itemarray",itemSelectedJson);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        final JsonObjectRequest objectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, INVEST_URL, jsonobj, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d("RESPONSE", response.toString());

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("JSONERROR",error.toString());
            }
        }){
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
                return headers;
            }
        };
 final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        queue.add(objectRequest);

    }
```

Comment: At which line getting issue?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I am loging the error inside on error response

Comment: Arrays are not objects. What do you want?

Comment: @Basilevs I want to insert an json array into mysql database

Comment: are you not getting json array like above..?

Comment: try to get first json object and from that json array

Comment: @KetanPatel I am both logging and displaying my json array it gives me a valid json array.Why cant i just send a json array directly.I am using volley here.

Comment: ok you getting json array right..? then you can convert to string and save  this string json array

Comment: @KetanPatel can you check the updated code please.Thamk You :)

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat thanks alot can you help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96646/discussion-between-androidnewbee-and-ketan-patel).

Comment: @AndroidNewBee you are welcome, and as you see you getting a JSONObject not a JSONArray, and this object contains the parameter `"msg":false` which may be an indication that you make something wrong in your request and that lead to you get a response with msg = false

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat can you help stuck with this for the past one week I cant really spot what I need to change.

Comment: it's about the request you send, the problem is in `itemSelectedJson` or `jsonObject`, there is something wrong with these objects, you have to see what you must send and make sure you are sending the right data, also you can fill `jsonObject` with a dummy data instead and see if it works, may be the problem is in a parameter you getting from one of your EditTexts or TextViews. Also check if you catch something through the catch block for `jsonObject.put` lines.

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat i tried doing both but i get the same response

Comment: So, the problem appears to be at the data that must sent in the request, may be you are sending data in a wrong format or with a wrong parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And I final got it to work this is my current code

```
 private void insertToDb() throws  JSONException{
        //createJsonArray();
        final String jsonArray = itemSelectedJson.toString().trim();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, INVEST_URL,


           new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    display.setText("This is the "+response);
                    Toast.makeText(AddInvEst.this, "This is the response"+response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d("RESPONSE", response.toString().trim());
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put(KEY_JSONARRAY,jsonArray);
            return params;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQ =Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQ.add(stringRequest);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

As in log:

> com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value
>   {"msg":false,"status":false}

Means Server is returning `JSONObject` instead of `JSONArray` as response String.

So, use `JsonObjectRequest` instead of `JsonArrayRequest` to make Volley request.

Comment: I tried making it a JSONObject but it gives an error JSONERROR: com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Comment: @AndroidNewBee: Show latest code and new error logs

Comment: @AndroidNewBee means not getting valid json String from server

Comment: I am trying to post the data not get it.

Comment: @AndroidNewBee: on no issue. just browser `JsonObjectRequest ` class and add debugger in `parseNetworkResponse ` then check what string you are getting from server in `jsonString `.

Comment: can you update your answer please I am new to programming thanks:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96636/discussion-between--k-and-androidnewbee).

Answer (score 1):

POST a JSONArray doesn't mean you need to call a JsonArrayRequest request.

Request depends on the type of the response you are expecting. You have to check the object type returned by your webservice and then adapt your request according to that.

In your specific case, the error log says you need to use a JsonObjectRequest instead of JsonArrayRequest.

Comment: I am already using Json object request please check the updated code towards the end I have added the current code

Comment: Now I am getting a Response
it say RESPONSE: {"msg":false,"status":false}

I get it at public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d("RESPONSE", response.toString());

            }

Comment: @AndroidNewBee great!